# Why I am not getting updated response in jersey 2 even after restarting tomcat server?

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I am just starting up with rest web services and using jersey to create one.

This is probably a lame question but kindly help as I am stuck. I have written a simple HelloWorld.java as given below.  This issue is I am updating the response string to "New Response" but it is keep showing the "Old Response" string value in browser. I have restarted the tomcat server after updating the string but keep getting the older response.

Not sure why it is not getting updated.

**HelloWorld.java**

```
package com.test;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;


@Path("/hello")
public class HelloWorld
{
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
  public String sayHelloXML()
  {
    String resource = "<h3> Old response</h3> ";
    return resource;
    
  }

  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public String sayHelloJSONEX()
  {
    String resource = null;
    return resource;
    
  }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
 http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>JerseyDemoWork</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
   <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
   <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
   <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
   <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
   <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list> 
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>JerseyDemoWork</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.test</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JerseyDemoWork</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Maybe it is some cache from the browser  ?

Comment: @Arnaud l am using inbuilt eclipse browser . How to fix this?